# Center label around anchor point in RelativeLayout with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a RelativeLayout, and multiple polygons/labels in it. Now I want to place the labels inside the polygons, in the center of it. However, I don't know the width and height of the label, so placing them in the center results in something like this: [image: hexagon]

However, this is wrong, as I want the label to be in the exact middle of the polygon (of which the width and height is known), no matter what the text is.

I've looked into methods to try to center it, for example using `HorizontalTextAlignment` and `VerticalTextAlignment`, but so far no success. What is the right way to do that? `HorizontalOptions` doesn't work either, as it's not relative to a parent or something.

Code I'm currently using:

```
var MainGrid = new RelativeLayout();
var path = new PointCollection();
// add points to path

var coords = new Point(100, 100);
var TILE_WIDTH = 70;
var TILE_HEIGHT = 80;

// Here the real code begins
polygon = new Polygon
{
    Points = path,
    <other arguments>
};
var text = new Label
{
    Text = "5",
    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
    VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
    TextColor = Color.Black,
};

MainGrid.Children.Add(
    polygon, 
    Constraint.Constant(coords.X),
    Constraint.Constant(coords.Y)
);
MainGrid.Children.Add(
    text,
    Constraint.Constant(coords.X + TILE_WIDTH / 2),
    Constraint.Constant(coords.Y + TILE_HEIGHT / 2)
);
```

Comment: instead of just *describing* the code, please post the relevant portions.  And how do you not know the width or height of the label?

Comment: Done, added some code I'm using

Comment: just set a Width and Height value when you create the label and base your calculations on that.  And temporarily set a BackgroundColor for the Label so you can visualize where it is being placed inside of the cell

Answer (score 1):

set an arbitrary width and height on the label, as long as it is big enough to fit your text and smaller than the polygon.  Also set a background color to help visualize the placement of the label (remove this once you get the alignment right)

```
var text = new Label
{
    Text = "5",
    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
    VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
    TextColor = Color.Black,
    BackgroundColor = Color.White,
    HeightRequest = 50,
    WidthRequest = 50
};
```

then factor in the label width and height when placing it

```
MainGrid.Children.Add(
    text,
    Constraint.Constant(coords.X + (TILE_WIDTH / 2) - 25),
    Constraint.Constant(coords.Y + (TILE_HEIGHT / 2) - 25)
);
```